# How to predefine dropdown button in Bootstrap using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to pre-define/select an option in the dropdown of a Bootstrap when the page with the drop down button loads.

This being my dropdown buttons:

```
<div class="btn-group">
    <a class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" id = "report" href="#">
        REPORTS
        <span class="caret1"></span>
    </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">NSE</a></li>
        <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">BSE</a></li>
        <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">MCX</a></li>
        <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">SX</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="btn-group">
    <a class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" id = "reportType" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
        TYPE
        <span class="caret"></span>
    </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" id = "reportType">
        <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">EQ</a></li>
        <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">FO</li>
        <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">CDS</a></li>
        <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">SX</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

and this my javascript:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

   // getUserData({{ data|safe }});

    $(this).parents(".btn-group").find('#report').text('NSE');
    $(this).parents(".btn-group").find('.caret').text('EQ');
    //document.getElementById("report").value= "Hide Filter";
});
```

I'm struggling to make it work.

How do I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Following is the way:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $(".dropdown-menu a").on('click', function(e) {
        var span = '<span class="caret"></span>';
        $(this).parents('.btn-group').find('a').eq(0).html($(this).text() +" "+ span);
    });

    $(".dropdown-menu a:contains('EQ')").trigger('click');
    $(".dropdown-menu a:contains('NSE')").trigger('click');
});
```

I added on click so that next time when you click some item, its shown as selected. Without on click, following is the code:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    var span = '<span class="caret"></span>';
    $("#report").html($(".dropdown-menu a:contains('EQ')").text() + span);
    $("#reportType").html($(".dropdown-menu a:contains('NSE')").text() + span);
});
```

Comment: The triggering isn't working, and I wantthe dropdown to populate without onClick.